# Advice for Denormalization

Tags: mysql, optimization, nosql, denormalization

I have a database of school districts (~15,000 of them and growing) and the retirement plans/benefits available to employees of each. The data is pretty well normalized:

- A district record is associated with 0 or *n* retirement plan options (where *n* < 10 spread out across 3 joined tables)
- A district record is associated with 0 or *n* benefits (where *n* is closer to 40 from 1 joined table)
- A district is also associated with a couple of other things where the number of associations is nominal.

Now the client wants to report. And they want to report in a very dynamic way (think about an iTunes smart playlist where rules can be added/removed for any property of any district, plan or benefit). I need to allow them to query on any property of a district, its retirement plans or its benefits and return *everything*.

In order to keep things simple (for now) and avoid duplicate data, I've setup a couple of views (shhh, I know) that just allow me to access the data in a way that any 1 district record effectively has a 1-to-1 relationship with the `all_retirement_plans` view and a 1-to-1 record with the `all_benefits_plans` view. This gives me a clean set of joins that results in a unified result set, but obviously comes with its own set of issues that I'm going to hit sooner rather than later...

Namely, it's going to get *ridiculously* slow as more data is added.

I'm looking for some advice on denormalization. I've thought about a reporting table that does what the views do, but can be indexed. I've also thought about dumping this entire set of district data out to MongoDB (or similar). I'm sure there are other options, but I'd be playing the trial and error game so I'm hoping someone here can advise me in a way that keeps me in the ballpark of a reasonable solution.

The bottom line is that I need to be able to store ~15,000 (and growing) district records along with a lot of additional meta data and then report on that data at a very granular level. Anyone have any thoughts or advice beyond where my own thinking has taken me? I'm trying to get ahead of the issues that I know are coming.

Comment: *"I've setup a couple of views (shhh, I know)..."* Views are a fundamental feature of SQL database management systems. When you have to use *views* and *shhh* right next to each other, you should consider switching to a different dbms.

Comment: I was being a bit goofy there, but the fact is, views probably aren't the right platform for this particular need. Given the size of the data (specifically the number of columns once denormalized), the views are just about as slow as I expected them to be. I'm not aware of any way to optimize them, but I'd love to be wrong.

Comment: One way to get better performance is to switch to a dbms that has a better query optimizer.

Comment: So are these `all_retirement_plans` and `all_benefits_plans` views using `GROUP_CONCAT` to aggregate and concatenate all the different strings?

Comment: @ruakh - If I understand your question, no. There is no string concatenation going on. I don't have exact numbers in front of me, but each district could have 0 or more of ~30 different benefits and a benefit record has a handful of properties. The `all_benefits_pans` view holds a district record containing each property of each benefit. It adds up to ~100 columns.

Comment: Oh, so are you performing a sort of `PIVOT`?

Comment: No. I'm not doing anything "fancy" yet. I threw this up as a quick, interim solution to get them started. It's a straight up view that joins several tables including one table (`benefits`) many times.

Comment: By "a sort of `PIVOT`" I mean, a conceptual pivot. MySQL doesn't support the actual `PIVOT` keyword, but you can use large numbers of `JOIN`s to achieve the approximate effect of a `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps as I've done a lot of work recently with moving data from relational to document oriented (denormalizing).

Some options with moving data to Mongo:

1. You can easily just write data from MySQL to Mongo and keep your relational tables. No transformations, just move the data straight over.  Mongo has map/reduce that can output to a new collection.  It's slow though.  =(  If you move a view straight over, Mongo has an aggregation framework that is very powerful for generating new documents.
2. Ideally you would compose your "document" in MySQL and then move those over.  My experience with MySQL is to make the document very flat.  You can add structure by being creative with group_concat.  You basically group_concat some data and manual JSON strings together.  (Ugly, but it works)
3. Mongo is *great* at working with documents.  Really, really great.  I highly recommend it if you want to work with denormalized data.
4. This might be overkill, but we use Mule ESB to move data from MySQL to Mongo.  You can do more complicated/tricky transformations there, but there is a learning curve.
5. In SQL Server you can output queries as XML.  If you can find a library to do that in MySQL, then it's an easy jump from XML to JSON.  We've been able to run queries in SQL Server over 100k records and output XML very quickly.

Let me know if you want more detail on any of the points. =)

Comment: Thanks, Ryan. I first wanted to be sure that if I moved to Mongo I could still perform very granular queries. A MongoDB "document" would represent a district (including all of its retirement plan/benefits data) so I could either include those as nested components or flatten it all out as you mentioned. Sounds like flat is faster? I'll have to look into `group_concat`.

Comment: Flat is easier to move from MySQL to Mongo. Mongo has a very rich query language. The syntax might take some getting used to, but you can definitely accomplish quite a lot. The group_concat can either create arrays or sub-documents.

Comment: Finally took a look at `group_concat`. That's not exactly what I have. I didn't concat field values so much as flatten records. If a district could have 3 possible benefits records (each w/ an ID and a provider), I flattened each of those benefits records into the view so that a district now has 1 benefits record w/ fields prefixed to distinguish. E.g., `accident_insurance_id`, `accident_insurance_provider`, `dental_id`, `dental_provider`, etc. Now my `districts` table has a 1-to-1 relationship with this view.

Comment: I guess, my initial thought would be to flatten a `district` so that the district document includes all retirement and benefits plan info in a MongoDB "document". Each district document would be pretty large (about 150 properties or so) and there would be 15-20K of these and growing. Any red flags in that guesstimate in terms of performance?

Comment: Yeah some things to note with Mongo and documents/document size. Mongo has a limit of 16MB for documents. You can't go over it. Also Mongo has a subtle assumption that your document won't grow too much. If it grows too big, Mongo has to move it out of its current memory location and find a new location. This can cause fragmentation of your RAM and make things slower. If some of your data is changing often, I would probably recommend linking to it with a reference instead of embedding it in the main document.